# Julia slows down after computer upgrade

Tags: performance, julia

I am very new to Julia and am not a computer geek so this question may not be very clear. I am happy to add any information as necessary.

I am running Julia on VSCode in Windows. I recently added some memory sticks (128G to 256G) to the PC and found out that Julia was significantly slower. I tried several things including moving the positions of the memory sticks, reinstalling Julia and VSCode, disabling hyperthreading. (in this order). Nothing worked.

I then decided to install Windows Server on my computer, hoping that Julia would behave normally under the new system. It was still slow.

Could anyone give me some suggestions on what to do? Thanks!

Comment: How much slower is it? If it's not that much, it might be unavoidable. You probably added RAM that is slower, so you have more RAM, but it takes longer to access. That will usually be slower.

Comment: Running the same code takes roughly twice the time. If I remembered correctly, the RAM was always 2133 or 2134 MHz.